# How do I change default directory in node.js? (Windows)

Tags: windows, node.js

When I try to tun my project on node, I have to write the full path for my javascript file because the default value node uses is `C:\Users\MyUser` and I refuse to use it.

I've been trying to find how to change this but have not found it anywhere. I even tried searching the directory manually for it and had no luck finding it.

Could anyone point me on how to fix this annoying little problem I have?

Comment: Node.js doesn't itself have a "*default directory*." The starting [working directory](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) ("[Home directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory)") is determined by Windows.

Comment: Wow, silly me! No wonder I could never find anything about this! You should post this as your answer.

Comment: Need some more info. Are you doing something like **> c:\Users\MyUser\node your_project** or **>node c:\users\MyUser\your_project** ?

Comment: Andyfan, I was doing the second one. What Jonathan said was my problem though (and I feel like such a noob for not noticing it).

Answer (score 7):

You can mean to change default directory for "Node.js command prompt", when you launch it. If so, then (Windows case)

1. go the directory where NodeJS was installed
2. find file nodevars.bat
3. open it with editor as administrator
4. change the default path in the row which looks like

   ```
   if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
   ```

with your path. It could be for example

```
    if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "c://MyDirectory/"
```

if you mean to change directory once when you launched "Node.js command prompt", then you can run in the command line of NodeJS command prompt:

```
     cd c:/MyDirectory/
```

Comment: For me this was: 
   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\"

Answer (score 1):

Node's "default" directory is the Windows home directory. Note, you can change node's home directory using [process.chdir(directory)](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_chdir_directory)

Answer (score -1):

There is a nodevars.bat file that launches the command shell in the programs folder.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your answer. Have a read of [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information. Also, once you get more reputation, you will be able to post this as a comment rather than an answer, which would be more appropriate.