# How to set the default working directory for node.js command prompt in Windows?

Tags: node.js, configuration, command-prompt, default

How can I change the directory that I'm in when I open node.js command prompt in Windows?

This question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128785/how-do-i-change-default-directory-in-node-js-windows?rq=1), but it was 5 years ago and the solution given does not work for me.

Here is the solution given in the last question:

---

1. go the directory where NodeJS was installed
2. find file nodevars.bat
3. open it with editor as administrator
4. change the default path in the row which looks like

   ```
   if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
   ```

with your path. It could be for example

```
    if "%CD%\"=="%~dp0" cd /d "c://MyDirectory/"
```

---

I did not find nodevars.bat where i expected it (as per point 1 above). So I did a PC-wide search and all that turned up was in `C:\Users\pieka\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v8.11.4` ("pieka" is my user name).

This may have something to do with the less widely used [node version manager for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) that I have installed - I am not sure.

More importantly, I edited `nodevars.bat` as per the answer, but my start-up directory remains unchanged when I open node.js command prompt.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895966/changing-default-startup-directory-for-command-prompt-in-windows-7), but it relates to Windows Command prompt, and to be honest I am not sure where to insert the code (`IF /I x"%COMSPEC%"==x%CMDCMDLINE% (cd /D c:\)`) that it suggests. Does the nodejs command prompt mimick the windows command prompt in terms starting directory?

Could I also achieve what I want by "opening" node.js command prompt from somewhere else than from the start menu?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the file in the wrong place. if you have not specified another path during installation, Node.js is installed in `c:\Program Files\nodejs`, and there is the `nodevars.bat`.