# webpack command of npm run dev from a new line

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

After finished specified command **npm run dev**, I can't again write new command in node console.

[image]

How can I continue to write from a new line?

Thanks, everybody for the help!

Comment: have you tried to open another Command Prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way. CTRL+C, after need to choose stop or not the execution of processing of listening and then will get a new line.

Comment: This way, the dev command (listening to changes and rebuilding) will be killed. I don't think, that's what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run dev` in most cases is intended to keep running, detect changes, re-transpile files and (hot) reload the application. That's intended behavior, so don't panic.

You should leave that terminal untouched and simply open a second one if you want to do anything else.

Comment: I am doing that, open again but it's uncomfortable for me.

Comment: You're not comfortable with using multiple terminal windows?

Comment: I need again specified a path to a folder of the project

Comment: That's a problem? You can set your terminal to open at the same location when opening a new one - or whatever. Depends on the terminal you're using, but that shouldn't be a problem honestly.

Comment: I found how setting the main folder of the project.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128785/how-do-i-change-default-directory-in-node-js-windows

Comment: I found the right way. CTRL+C, after need to choose stop or not the execution of processing of listening and then will get a new line.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open another terminal window. The reason is that webpack is now listening for changes - meaning the process in your current terminal window is still running. 
Opening another terminal window will allow you to run other commands while the webpack process is still running.

Comment: Ok. But I need again specified a path to a folder of the project.